# Is it possible to find out which questions were affected? "removed +30 User was removed (learn more)"

Tags: discussion, reputation

I'd thought for a while that someone was periodically downvoting my answers, normally right after posting, but smart enough not to get caught immediately.  I'd presumed it was a sock puppet account.

Yesterday, out of the blue, I received a rep bump saying:

> removed +30 User was removed ([learn more](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/user-was-removed))

I was wondering if it's possible to find out which answers (or questions) have been affected by removing this user, obviously I don't know who the user is.

Comment: The gist of the duplicate is *"available via the Stack Exchange API"*.